# How to connect component (file) to redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-router, react-redux

I need to create `component/file/class` whatever and connect it to redux store.
I don't need this component to be rendered.
It's just a helper component which can contain methods that return value from store.
I tried to create a file with:

```
export function getKeyFromReduxStore(key:string) {...
```

but this is just a file that export function and I can't (or don't know) how to connect it to redux store.
All my components are connected with store throught:

```
<RouterWithRedux>
          <Scene key="root">...
```

but as I said this is no scene it's just helper component that I want to reuse through whole app.
How can I make such a component and connect it to redux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redux store has a method called `getState` which gets the state of the store. You can import the store you have created in the file where redux store is required.

```js
// in the file where you created your store
import { createStore } from 'redux';

export const myStore = createStore(
  // ... some middleware or reducer etc
)

// in your component/file/class
import { myStore } from '../path/to/store'

export function getKeyFromReduxStore(key:string) {
  return (myStore.getState())[key];
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass in the store to `getKeyFromReduxStore` function and call it in react component where store would be available. For instance in the `mapStateToProps` function:

```js
// component/file/class
export function getKeyFromReduxStore(store, key) {
  return store[key];
}


// react component with access to store
import { getKeyFromReduxStore } from '../path/to/file';

class MyKlass extends Component {
  // ... your logic
  render() {
    const val = this.props.getKey(someVal);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  getKey: (key) => getKeyFromReduxStore(store, key),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyKlass);
```